# Calculate memory address c#

Tags: c#, memory, offset, radix, readprocessmemory

How do I find the new memory address in C# using my static address and offset.

> base: 0x1023469C
>
> offset: 1E8

I tried just adding the offset to the base inside of the `readprocessmemory` function but that didn't work at all :(
I am trying to read memory from this address as I am programming a little tool which will play a sound if my health in justcause 2 gets to low.
thanks for your help in advance :D

This is what I got so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //variabeln JC2
    //Pointer
    const int Offset = 0x1E8; // offset
    const int Base = 0x1023469C; // base
    const string Game = "The Game you don't know"; //Name

   

    //permission to read process memory
    const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010; //needed for reading memory


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
    int dwSize,
    out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BTcheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Game).Length > 0)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(Game)[0];
            IntPtr procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);

            IntPtr baseAddress = new IntPtr(Base); //whatever address you wish
            int offset = Offset; //whatever offset you wish
            baseAddress += offset;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(int)]; //select a proper buffer size
            int read = -1;

            ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, baseAddress, buffer, buffer.Length, out read); 

                            if (read == buffer.Length)
            {
                int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
                //do something with it
                
                LBcurrent.Text = Convert.ToString(value); //display the value
            }
        }

        else
        { LBcurrent.Text = "Error!"; }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What exactly "does not work at all"? Can you elaborate? You left us guessing, here...

Comment: I am trying to get read the value of a dynamic memory address. There for I need to calculate the address using the pointer (static address and offset).

Comment: I tried: ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, Address, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead); Now I do not know how to get my address using the pointer...

Comment: Do you want to read the address of a reference type you have created or to get an access to a memory space of some process?

Comment: To get acces to a memory space of some process.

Comment: Try again - what are you trying to do? The real problem, not the generalization you've devised to solve your actual problem. Why are you trying to use `ReadProcessMemory` in C#?

Comment: I am making a program that plays a warning sound if my health in justcause 2 is getting low.

Comment: See, much better :) Now edit that into your question and we can go on with the answering part :))

Comment: So, how did you actually get the "base and offset" of the memory you're trying to read? Memory allocation isn't necessarily deterministict (the memory location could have changed in the meantime, for example; this is even worse with managed memory languages), and there's a few special segments you still have to care about (e.g. thread-local storage etc.). Did you use some debugger to find the original address? Also, you could have a look at https://github.com/Luaancz/AutoPoke, it handles searching, reading and writing foreign process memory - it might help a bit.

Comment: I found it using olldbg and confirmed the address and offset using cheatengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it (tested):

For the function import:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
IntPtr hProcess,
IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
[Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
int dwSize,
out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

For using it:

```
IntPtr procHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
IntPtr baseAddress = new IntPtr(0x027EF131); //whatever address you wish
int offset = 0x100; //whatever offset you wish
baseAddress += offset;
byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
int read = -1;

ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, baseAddress, buffer, buffer.Length, out read);

if (read == buffer.Length)
{
    int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
    //do something with it
}
```

EDIT:
I've assumed you were trying to read from the current process memory, hence the `procHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;` part. Feel free to change that handle to whatever process handle you require and have permissions to.

EDIT:
I've edited the answer for reading 32-bit integet values. For 64 bit, use sizeof(long) for the buffer size and BitConverter.ToInt64.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have uploaded my source because I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I only get weird chinese symbols when trying to read the memory.

Comment: Are you sure it's Unicode text there? Give ASCII a try.

Comment: Also, are sure it's text? 4 bytes is just two Unicode characters... Or 4 ASCII characters. Maybe it's a 32 bit integer.

Comment: I updated my code but it still does not work... I get System.Byte[] (not [ ], but some sort of rectangle that looks like [ ]). Could it be, that it doesn't work because I am trying to read from a 64bit process?

Comment: What's the value of read right after the ReadProcessMemory call?

Comment: the same as the number of bytes (10)

Comment: Please check in a debugger what bytes are stored at that particular address you are using, compare it with what's in buffer after the call to ReadProcessMemory and then, also, do a paste here.

Comment: The address stores an Integer between 0 an 30. I do not really know how to check what the value of the buffer is... When I enter the Breakmode in Visual Studio and right click on buffer and then select Quickwatch I get the value of buffer = "The name 'buffer' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: So why are you converting it to string, then?

Comment: Are you shure that your code is correct? I tried it with several Bases and Offsets, but it still does not work... Is the part: baseAddress += offset; correct? cause that part of the code does not make any sense to me. Also I updated my source.

Comment: Yes, the code is correct and verified. It also answers your question: how to add an offset to a base address. I suggest you do some more reading before going into this kind of depth.

Comment: "Does not work" is not fit on stackoverflow. You have to say what exactly you measure and how you measure or what error are you getting.

Comment: Btw, your constant PROCESS_WM_READ should actually be called PROCESS_VM_READ as stated here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Also, for fixing other issues regarding your code, I suggest you post other questions. I will no longer answer here, since I consider the question already got a response. Feel free to post here links to other questions you post and I will try to answer those, too.